# lotusscript : how can i check if user press "Enter Button from keyboard" in msgbox?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

i have a problem.

msgbox can press enter from keyboard for "OK"

i need to trap user who press enter from keyboard in msgbox
(need to let them click ok buton than)

thx

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with the default messagebox / msgbox function in Notes.

You need to create your own messagebox- form and use NotesUIWorkspace.Dialogbox instead of msgbox. In your own form you can use QueryClose- Event to prohibit closing without clicking OK button.